# Copy all webpage text to clipboard with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if there was a way to select all text on a web page, and copy it to clipboard on button click.

I have a PHP script that `echo`s the output of `dmesg` on my server, and I want a way to copy all text on button click.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one output on one page. you can use XML HTTP Request (XHR) to get the content of the page, store the response of XHR request and then use clipboard.js (https://clipboardjs.com/) to copy the content to the clipboard

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Pass the element you want to this function on click of a button:

```
function selectText(element) {
    var doc = document
        , text = element
        , range, selection
    ;
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) { //ms
        range = doc.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) { //all others
        selection = window.getSelection();
        range = doc.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
}
```

read more about it [here](http://www.satya-weblog.com/2013/11/javascript-select-all-content-html-element.html)